# UITableView not updating during data retrieval from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On launch, I have the app set to retrieve data from Firebase, create objects, and add them to an array where they are added to a UITableView. Even though each object is created individually, the items are created but not added to the UITableView until every object from the data is created.

Firebase runs on the main thread which, so it's not a GCD issue. I am running retrieveData() in the viewDidLoad.

It seems the items are put in memory (not added to the tableview?) and continue to stack up until all items are created. At that point, everything is loaded into the tableview and the memory usage is back to normal. This results in extremely high memory usage and a crash if there are enough items.

```
func retrieveData(){
    let dateString = getDate()
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("orders/").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child(dateString).child("products").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        if (value != nil){
            for (key) in value! {
                let item = key.value as? [String:Any]
                let (barcode, name, _, bottleSize) = self.getInfo(code: item!["code"]! as! String)
                self.generateItem(barcode: barcode, name: name, bottleSize: bottleSize, quantity: item!["quantity"]! as! String, isInitial: true)
            }
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


func generateItem(barcode: String, name: String, bottleSize: String, quantity: String, isInitial: Bool = false) {
    let i = item(code: barcode, name: name, size: bottleSize, quantity: quantity)
    order.append(i)

    print("Item Created --- ", order[order.count - 1].name,order[order.count - 1].quantity,order[order.count - 1].code)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: order.count - 1, section: 0)
    orderTableView.beginUpdates()
    orderTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    orderTableView.endUpdates()

    // Update Firebase database
    if (isInitial == false){
        updateDatabase()
    }
}
```

Comment: try `reloadData()` on your tableView and that should work

Answer (score 0):

First try to construct the `item` object and append to array, then call `reloadData()` directly. See how it works.

```
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    if (value != nil){
        for (key) in value! {
            let item = key.value as? [String:Any]
            let (barcode, name, _, bottleSize) = self.getInfo(code: item!["code"]! as! String)
            let i = item(code: barcode, name: name, size: bottleSize, quantity: quantity)
            order.append(i)
        }
        orderTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! After using your idea, I think the problem actually has nothing to do with the tableview. Without reloading the tableview and only appending the item to the array, I noticed that the memory usage is still ridiculously high (reaches ~600MB before it finishes). Perhaps the real issue has to do with the Firebase call?

Comment: @3x14 I've been using Firebase for a few projects, that didn't happen to me. Did you try Instrument to monitor? Btw, I think Firebase has a performance tool as well.

Comment: Looks like there's a ton of this: "HashableTypedNativeDictionaryStorage<String, Any>" that is growing. Not really sure how to fix this though.